# How to get parent process events?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have two winform projects (lets call `p1` and `p2`) and I am setting one of the process's panel as parent of the other. I mean, I am calling `p2.exe` in my `p1` project as given below,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

p2 = Process.Start(@"mypath../p2.exe");
SetParent(p2.MainWindowHandle,_myContainer.Handle);
```

I set some mouseclick events for parent panel (`_myContainer`) of `p1` project and I want to raised them on click actions. But mouse click actions perfom on child winform (`p2` form) as usual. Is there any way to raised panel events of parent panel instead of child form?

---

first of all, sorry about my english.

i have a very large project and most of features, integrations on it. However, on my last integration process, i had a problem. The point is, i can perfectly control all functions of engine on my single project but when integrated to my main project, whenever i activated a specific function of engine, i am loosing connection. And, unfortunately i could't detect the reason, maybe there are some .dll conflicts or architectural problem. Anyway... As a solution for now, my single project (child form) is parented by my main project panel. i am already partly controlling child form by a shared file. i am sending action commands from main project and child form listens that file if changed, and take actions, For example parent panel resizing. Now, i stuck on one point, my main project have many panels, each panel has a control and right click on any panel brings the common action list for all.  Except the panel that parents the child form i have integration problems, because, as expected, click action is happening on child form, parent panel event not being raised, user can't see action list and looks like loose of main-project functionality. So, i wonder if there is any **simple** way to call parent panel events instead of child form? Because i want to keep coherent of main user interface -getting action list at every panel by clicking- and i am planning to control child form throught shared file.

Comment: Are you actually talking about raising events?  Or do you mean *handling* events?  Why would you want to *raise* a mouse-click event?

Comment: You're trying to make a control in one process a parent of a control in another process? Why? What are you trying to accomplish? Do you really think you know enough about the window model to make this work correctly? Do you realize the message loops for the two processes must be merged? Do you understand the implications? Do you understand everything in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683 ?

Comment: yes i am asking if it s possible to control events in another process @Luaan . I explained the reason by editing my message. i understand somethings like the link you shared but i know i have some lack of information like merging message loops. That s why i am asking in fact? if you know, i will appriciate to guide me, otherwise your comment looks like out of purpose